# How do you prevent (click) from adding the class to all elements in a ngFor?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a mobile nav that is constructed dynamically with a ngFor. In that nav some items will have drop downs. On desktop this is handled with hover. However on mobile I created a click event. Using a:active is not an option from my UX team. we want the user to click the nav item and be able to open and close the dropdown. The issues I am having is the ngFor puts the click on ever nav item, and not just the ones with dropdowns, and when you click on it it adds the class to all elements with a drop down so all dropdowns get opened, not just the child of the one you click.

Here is my html

```
<div id="mobNav" [ngClass]="{'toggleNav': isClassVisible}">
                            <ul class="navList">
                                <li class="root" *ngFor='let item of topMenu' (click)="toggleClass()" [ngClass]="{'more' : !item.url}">
                                    <a class="txt">{{item.name}}</a>
                                    <!--Mobile-->
                                    <ul *ngIf="!item.url" class="dropDown" [ngClass]="{'toggleMobileNav' : isMobileVisible}">
                                        <li *ngFor="let sItem of findChildren(item.tabID) " class="txt ">
                                            <a href="{{ sItem.url }} ">{{ sItem.name }}</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

Here is my method I am calling. Nothing special here

```
  toggleClass(){
this.isMobileVisible = !this.isMobileVisible;
if(this.isMobileVisible === true){
  console.log("class added");

}      else{
    console.log("class not added");
  }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change a bit the HTML, create separate HTML for your cases, then move the `(click)` from `<li>` to the corresponding element.

Sample (HTML structure has changed therefore also the CSS might need to change):

```
<div id="mobNav" [ngClass]="{'toggleNav': isClassVisible}">
    <ul class="navList">
        <li class="root" *ngFor='let item of topMenu' [ngClass]="{'more' : !item.url}">
            <a *ngIf="item.url">
                <span class="txt">{{item.name}}</span>
            </a>
            <a *ngIf="!item.url" (click)="toggleClass(item)">
                <span class="txt">{{item.name}}</span>
                <!--Mobile-->
                <ul class="dropDown" [ngClass]="{'toggleMobileNav' : item.isMobileVisible}">
                    <li *ngFor="let sItem of findChildren(item.tabID) " class="txt ">
                        <a href="{{ sItem.url }} ">{{ sItem.name }}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Also you can change the function in order to work with each item individually:

```
toggleClass(item){
    item.isMobileVisible = !item.isMobileVisible;
    if(item.isMobileVisible === true){
        console.log("class added", item);

    }      else{
        console.log("class not added", item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Works like a charm